# ResultSet not populating with results

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am attempting to pull results from an Oracle database. I have written a query that is correct, and produces accurate results when issued manually in sqlplus. Furthermore, the code works as expected when when the query matches only one row (In other words, when the ResultSet has only one row, everything works). However, when more than one row match the query, the ResultSet returned by the Oracle JDBC is empty.

```
public Component[] getAllComponents(int typeId, int osId) throws SQLException
{
    String query= "SELECT c.component_id, c.component_name, c.component_version, c.type_id, c.post_download_instructions, "
                + "o.os_id, o.os_name, o.description AS os_description, "
                + "i.file_location, i.release_date, i.patch_number, i.file_id, "
                + "i.description AS i_description "
                + "FROM components c, installation_files i, operating_systems o "
                + "WHERE c.type_id = ? " 
                + "AND i.os_id = ? " 
                + "AND c.component_id = i.component_id "
                + "AND i.os_id = o.os_id";

    ResultSet results       = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt  = null;
    ArrayList<Component> found = new ArrayList<Component>();

    try {
        stmt = dbConn.prepareStatement(query); //dbConn is member variable

        stmt.setInt(1, typeId);
        stmt.setInt(2, osId);

        results = stmt.executeQuery();

        while(results.next()){
            //Some logic
        }

    } finally {
        if(results != null) results.close();
        if(stmt != null) stmt.close();
        dbConn.close();
    }

    //More Code
    //etc. etc.
```

Inspecting the ResultSet shows that calling ResultSet.next() never produces `true` when the fetched results should contain more than one row. However, issuing the query manually does produce results, and when only one row is returned, everything works fine. Does anyone know what's going on? I'm using Oracle's ojdbc6.jar.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you're not working with the database you think you're working with? Maybe you've multiple DBs, one for production, one for test environment, one for local development, etc. Doublecheck the JDBC URL. Or perhaps you're not specifying the `typeId` and/or `osId` you think you're specifying? Debug them.

Comment: Yep, i would double check your config. This code seems to be fine.

Comment: You could check a 'SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL'. If that is working then something is wrong with your query or your parameters.

Comment: It is very difficult to say what is happening. Saw your code and it seems fine. Please share table stucture and data as well.

Comment: I checked the parameters and they're what I expect. The connection seems to be fine since the ResultSet is accurately populated when only one result is returned. Selecting from DUAL works...

Comment: Just ran your code with different table (personal one), it is working fine.

Comment: What happen if you remove all '?' condition?

Answer (score 0):

Before that query you can check if there really are some components with `COUNT(*)` instead of all fields. Then run your query only if `COUNT(*)` is one or more.